# Best advice on Frayed, exposed wires on air purifier cord

Tags: electrical, wiring

I was cleaning my air purifier today and saw exposed wires on the cord (photo attached). It's hard to see but it looks like this part of the cord has been flattened/run down and then popped open, but it has never been placed in between a door or in an area where it's stepped on. This has me thinking it might have been an issue since I've had it -- 2-2.5 years. Can anyone recommend the best way to replace this cord? Temporarily, I will cover it with electrical tape, but long term I'd want to replace it since I run it all the time.

FYI - I'm in the US.

Brand of Purifier: https://www.envionproducts.com/images/TPP230H_Mnl_3.15_R1.pdf

Photo of breakage: [image: Wire Breakage]

Comment: Yeah, and that's the hot wire, too.

Comment: looks like the insulation has been scraped off ... did someone run a vacuum cleaner power brush over it? .... cut it off and put a plug on the end  then use an extension cord if needed

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say how bad the wire is damaged but it could be dangerous so it's good you found out about it. Make sure you unplug it before wrapping electrical tape around the cord.

Replacing the cord is a necessity. I replaced a cord on a Sharper Image air filter and I had to just about disassemble the entire unit to get to where the cord was attached to the unit. Unless you're very handy I wouldn't advise you doing this. Take it to an appliance repair shop or check with the manufacturer about having them fix it. I know this is a DIY site but sometimes we just have to bit the bullet and recommend getting a pro involved.

Comment: Replacing cords is sometimes doable, sometimes not. But if you know how to replace a cord then you probably wouldn't be asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

Cut the cord off, while not plugged in, about 3 inches apart.  Cut the left side in the center of the fray and the right side ~3 inches above, separate the wires.  Slide appropriate sized heat shrink tube over the cord.  Solder the wires back together.  Slide heat shrink over the damaged area and heat until tubing is tight to cord.  This isn't going to be water tight but should work for casual use.

Comment: I don't think you can make a mechanically sound soldersplice (Western Union style) in stranded cordage wire...